# react native NativeBase CheckBox not working

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using:
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",

I have used checkbox and made a custom checkboxGroup and it was working. now I want to create a customCheckBox but it doesn't do anything,it's not getting checked, I even can not change it's color.

I tried to use it the simplest way possible as document says but it's still not working with a blue color.

here is what it looks like https://pasteboard.co/Ila4cfR.png

```
    const CustomChBx = ({label, onPress, disabled, checked, textStyle}) => {
        const {_chbx, _label, _wrapper} = styles;
        return (
            <View style={_wrapper}>
                <Text style={[_label, textStyle]}>{label}</Text>
                <CheckBox>
                    style={_chbx}
                    checked={checked}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    onPress={onPress}
                    color={Colors.accentColor}
                </CheckBox>
            </View>
        );
    };
```

Comment: Create custom checkbox like this :https://reactnativecode.com/custom-checkbox-component/

Answer (score 0):

i copied and pasted this code and then edited it, it's working !!!

```
<ListItem>
    CheckBox checked={true} />
    <Body>
        <Text>Daily Stand Up</Text>
    </Body>
</ListItem>
```